# Nullsoft Installer (NSIS) Get Value and save to file

Tags: nsis

am working on an installer for specific tinc-vpn installations. I need to have nullsoft installer ask me for two things:

1. The VPN address
2. The name of the computer on the VPN network.

These values will be written to text files by the installer (that's a later step).

for now, I am trying to figure out how to access the vars once they have been put in.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 !include LogicLib.nsh
 !include nsDialogs.nsh

 Name nsDialogs
 OutFile nsDialogs.exe

 XPStyle on

 Var Dialog
 Var Label1
 Var Label2
 Var IPAddr
 Var VPNName

 Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave
 Page instfiles

 Function nsDialogsPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $Dialog

${If} $Dialog == error
    Abort
${EndIf}

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "What's Your IP Address on the VPN?"
Pop $Label1

${NSD_CreateText} 0 12u 100% 12u ""
Pop $IPAddr

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 24u 100% 12u "What's Your IP Address on the VPN?"
Pop $Label2

${NSD_CreateText} 0 36u 100% 12u ""
Pop $VPNName

nsDialogs::Show

 FunctionEnd

 Function nsDialogsPageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $VPNName $0
DetailPrint "VPN Name: $0"
 Function End

 Section

 SectionEnd
```

This, of course, fails in the compiler. Does anyone know how to make this work? I just want to do something simple: prompt for a text value, then store that text value in a text file, and copy that file to a desination...

Answer (score 1):

There were some syntax errors in your script.

How do you compile your file? Do you use some editor - HM NIS Edit, Visual Studio or pure notepad?

In all cases NSIS compiles tells you where (which line) the error is.

Here is fixed script:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
 !include nsDialogs.nsh

 Name nsDialogs
 OutFile nsDialogs.exe

 XPStyle on

 Var Dialog
 Var Label1
 Var Label2
 Var IPAddr
 Var VPNName

 Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave
 Page instfiles

 Function nsDialogsPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $Dialog

${If} $Dialog == error
    Abort
${EndIf}

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "What's Your IP Address on the VPN?"
Pop $Label1

${NSD_CreateText} 0 12u 100% 12u ""
Pop $IPAddr

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 24u 100% 12u "What's Your VPN name?"
Pop $Label2

${NSD_CreateText} 0 36u 100% 12u ""
Pop $VPNName

nsDialogs::Show

 FunctionEnd

 Function nsDialogsPageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $VPNName $0
${NSD_GetText} $IPAddr $1
MessageBox MB_OK "VPN Name: $0, IP: $1"
 FunctionEnd

 Section main

 SectionEnd
```

Use **MessageBox** instead of DetailPrint because DetailPrint is used to add messages into install page and you want to show something when install page is not initialized yet.

Comment: Actually, I do want to show information on the install page, and not a message box.

Comment: Then remember the information in variable and show it later, as I said - you cannot use DetailsPrint when Install page is not shown.